# Change element width inside AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have such code in my directive link :

```
        scope.parentWidth = function (){
            return{'width':element.parent().width()}
        }


        scope.$watch(scope.parentWidth, function(oldValue, newValue) {
            if (oldValue !== newValue) {
                element.css('width', newValue);
                console.log(element.width());
            }
        }, true);
```

But in console I see that width is the same every time(element is a simple div). even when `newValue` changed. Am i doing smth wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.$watch('parentWidth', function(oldValue, newValue) {
            if (oldValue !== newValue) {
                element.css('width', newValue +'px');
                console.log(element.width());
            }
        }, true);
```

When watching a property of the scope just supply it as a string otherwise the first argument can be a simple idempotent function as well

```
scope.$watch(function(){return scope.parentWidth;}, function(oldValue, newValue) {
            if (oldValue !== newValue) {
                element.css('width', newValue +'px');
                console.log(element.width());
            }
        }, true);
```

Comment: Actualy, It doesn matter in case of question. `parenWidth` changes properly, but width of `element` every time is the same, so `element.css('width', newValue);` doesn`t set the width of element.

Comment: Give it a shot with the +'px' sometimes this matters when trying to set a style I'm assuming here you're getting the console.log but it's just not changing value?

Comment: Yes, I have log but width is the same.